# Issues with a global setting for forest

Tags: forest

I want to draw a decision tree using Latex and forest. Therefore, I found the following relevant question, see  [How to draw a proper decision tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289642/how-to-draw-a-proper-decision-tree/289683#289683?newreg=e65ed093b1d44e03aac67a9f1f72615d)

The selected answer pretty much satisfies my needs.
However, I am not able to reproduce the output.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\forestset{
    .style={
        for tree={
            base=bottom,
            child anchor=north,
            align=center,
            s sep+=1cm,
    straight edge/.style={
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},thick,-{Latex}] 
        (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor);}
        },
     if n children={0}
        {tier=word, draw, thick, rectangle}
        {draw, diamond, thick, aspect=2},
    if n=1{%
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},thick,-{Latex}] 
        (!u.parent anchor) -| (.child anchor) node[pos=.2, above] {Y};}
        }{
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},thick,-{Latex}] 
        (!u.parent anchor) -| (.child anchor) node[pos=.2, above] {N};}
        }
        }
     }
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
 [$x_2$, tikz={\draw[{Latex}-, thick] (.north) --++ (0,1);}
    [$x_1$
        [1] 
        [0] 
    ]   
    [$x_3$
        [$x_1$
           [1] 
           [0] 
        ]   
        [0] 
     ]   
 ] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Using the provided source code, the result is:

[image: Output of provided source code]

Integrating the `for tree` statement into the forest block, however, works better, but does not lead to the expected output.
The arrows overlay with the nodes.

[image: Own solution]

Some information about the used versions

- Operating system: ubuntu 17.10
- Forest: v2.1.5
- Tikz: v3.0.1a

I have already looked into the current documentation of forest but was not able to find something that has changed for the current version of forest.

So, my main questions are:

- How can I state a global configuration for forest trees?
- Why is `\forestset` not working properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello! I have an off topic question regarding TeX.SX. Which answer should I accept if I use a combination of multiple answers for my solution?

Comment: I personally think that cfr’s answer is better than mine ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.style` was never supported and, as I understand it (from Forest's manual, which documents the change extensively), it never did work properly. In current versions of Forest, it does not work at all, but `default preamble`, as Jasper Habicht mentioned, does.

If you want this as the default style, I assume you are using it multiple times. In that case, I would simplify the code and try to make it as flexible and automatic as possible. In particular, I would try to avoid hard-coding dimensions required to avoid clashes by handling the problem in a way which gets `forest` to figure out a sensible layout.

This can be done, I think, by making use of some of the dedicated growth-direction-aware anchors provided. (Many which did not exist in version 1 of the package.)

For example, you might consider something like the following.

```
\forestset{
  default preamble={
    before typesetting nodes={
      !r.replace by={[, coordinate, append]}
```

This will automatically add a fake root, so that the arrow from above doesn't need to be drawn in manually. This helps to prevent inconsistencies in e.g. line width and distances from creeping in during editing.

```
    },
    where n children=0{
      tier=word,
    }{
      diamond, aspect=2,
    },
```

This is essentially the original code, slimmed down, for treating terminal nodes differently from the rest.

```
    where level=0{}{
```

Don't do anything for the first node (this is the actual, original root), as we don't want labels here.

```
      if n=1{
        edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {Y}},
      }{
        edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {N}},
      }
```

This sets the labelling. I don't know why the code you sourced didn't use `edge label` as this facility is not new at all and was certainly available in version 1.

```
    },
    for tree={
      edge+={thick, -Latex},
```

Consistent edges.

```
      math content,
```

It's all maths, so let's not have to type `$...$` all the time.

```
      s sep'+=1cm,
```

A bit faster than the original (not available in version 1.)

```
      draw,
      thick,
      edge path'={ (!u) -| (.parent)},
```

This is the bit which avoids fiddling with hard-coded nudges to nodes to get things spaced out. `edge path'` was not available in version 1. It wraps its argument to construct a complete path, including the `edge label` (which the code in your question eliminated for some reason). `.parent` refers here to an anchor of the current node i.e. the child. It is a point on its border in the direction of its parent. (Well, usually.)

By using `!u` rather than a specific anchor, we get Ti*k*Z to figure out where on the border of the diamonds to draw to. This means we don't need different definitions for left and right branches. It also means we don't have to hard-code a compass-direction, as this will auto-adjust according to the tree's direction of growth etc.,  just as `.parent` does.

```
    }
  }
}
```

And we're done.

[image: a semi-automatically constructed decision tree]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\forestset{
  default preamble={
    before typesetting nodes={
      !r.replace by={[, coordinate, append]}
    },
    where n children=0{
      tier=word,
    }{
      diamond, aspect=2,
    },
    where level=0{}{
      if n=1{
        edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {Y}},
      }{
        edge label={node[pos=.2, above] {N}},
      }
    },
    for tree={
      edge+={thick, -Latex},
      math content,
      s sep'+=1cm,
      draw,
      thick,
      edge path'={ (!u) -| (.parent)},
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest} 
    [x_2
        [x_1
            [1] 
            [0] 
        ]   
        [x_3
            [x_1
              [1] 
              [0] 
            ]   
            [0] 
        ]   
    ] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the default style that you provided and it works well for my actual decision tree. However, I had to adapt the aspect to 1.25 as Jasper Habicht mentioned. Maybe, this is required, since I embed the forest statement into a subfigure statement. While the subfigure environment cannot scale the forest environment (float), I use \resizebox for this issue. What is considered as a useful method to scale a forest float?

Comment: @Bromi Well, not scaling is best. If you must scale, it is better to use `tikzscale` than `\resizebox`. With Forest trees, though, usually just adding `font=\small` or `font=\footnotesize` in the `for tree={}` is enough and will give better results.

Answer (score 3):

First, according to the package documentation, the proper default styling of forests (at least in version 2+) is to use `default preamble` in `\forestset`.

(Edit: I just read that you are using version 2+ of the `forest` package. The default set-up indeed has changed from version 1 which may be the reason why the code does not result in the desired output.)

Second, in order to make the arrows not overlap the nodes, you either have to change the aspect of the diamonds to make the nodes somewhat narrower, or you have to increase the distance of the lowest level nodes.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\forestset{
    default preamble={
        for tree={
            base=bottom,
            child anchor=north,
            align=center,
            s sep+=1cm,                      % or use: s sep +=1.5 cm ...
    straight edge/.style={
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},thick,-{Latex}] 
        (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor);}
        },
    if n children={0}
        {tier=word, draw, thick, rectangle}
        {draw, diamond, aspect=1.25, thick}, % ... and retain: aspect=2
    if n=1{%
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},thick,-{Latex}] 
        (!u.parent anchor) -| (.child anchor) node[pos=.2, above] {Y};}
        }{
        edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge},thick,-{Latex}] 
        (!u.parent anchor) -| (.child anchor) node[pos=.2, above] {N};}
        }
        }
     }
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 [$x_2$, tikz={\draw[{Latex}-, thick] (.north) --++ (0,1);}
    [$x_1$
        [1] 
        [0] 
    ]   
    [$x_3$
        [$x_1$
           [1] 
           [0] 
        ]   
        [0] 
     ]   
 ] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

With `s sep+=1cm` and `aspect=1.25`:

[image]

… or with `s sep+=1.5cm` and `aspect=2`:

[image]

Comment: The `.style` was never supposed to work, never worked properly and broke entirely, as you note, in the upgrade from 1 to 2.